# Datetime header when reading in a file with pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

So far I have a data set that kind of looks like this:

```
2011-11-01 05:20:00 00:10:00
#    z  speed    dir      W   sigW       bck   error 
30   4.76  238.9   0.01   0.13  7.56E+06       0
40   5.24  237.1  -0.05   0.12  5.99E+06       0
50   6.33  236.6  -0.01   0.12  7.24E+06       0
60   7.06  237.3  -0.01   0.12  9.15E+06       0
70   7.85  238.2  -0.02   0.13  8.47E+06       0
80   8.85  237.3  -0.03   0.14  1.05E+07     256

2011-11-01 05:30:00 00:10:00
#    z  speed    dir      W   sigW       bck   error 
30   4.40  234.8   0.08   0.12  1.33E+07       0
40   5.07  234.2   0.11   0.12  5.82E+06       0
50   5.75  234.3   0.12   0.12  6.61E+06       0
60   6.56  232.4   0.08   0.13  6.39E+06       0
70   7.22  233.2   0.10   0.13  5.64E+06       0
80   8.15  235.3   0.12   0.14  5.87E+06     256
```

Where every ten minutes for the whole day it seperates into blocks of data like this with date time headers. I want to read in these headers and store them as a time variable. So far I have read it in like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filename = glob.glob('1511??.mnd')
data_nov15_hereford = pd.DataFrame()
frames = []
dates = []

for i in filename:
   f_nov15_hereford = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows = 32, sep='\s+')
counter = 1
for line in i:
   if counter % 31 == 0:
   dates.append(parse_date(line))
   counter = 0
else:
    counter += 1
   frames.append(f_nov15_hereford) 
data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
data_nov15_hereford = data_nov15_hereford.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

hub_wspd = data_nov15_hereford[data_nov15_hereford['#'] == 80].z
```

The skiprows statement is skipping these time headers for now. I have a variable hub_wspd that I am interested along with the time headers. Is there a way to read in these time headers and store them as variables without messing up what I have already done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store them as a datetime you could do write a small method to return a `datetime` variable after parsing the header line.

Something like this

```
import datetime

def parse_date(string):
    # Split the string into year/month/date, time, and seconds
    split_string = string.split()
    # get year month and date
    year = split_string[0].split('-')[0]
    month = split_string[0].split('-')[1]
    date = split_string[0].split('-')[2]

    # get hour minute second
    hour = split_string[1].split(':')[0]
    min = split_string[1].split(':')[1]
    second = split_string[1].split(':')[2]

    return datetime.datetime(year, month, date, hour=hour, minute=min, second=second)
```

[datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html)

EDIT - Do away with the counter entirely and just look for lines that start with '20':

```
def parse_date(string):
    # Split the string into year/month/date, time, and seconds
    split_string = string.split()
    # get year month and date
    year = split_string[0].split('-')[0]
    month = split_string[0].split('-')[1]
    date = split_string[0].split('-')[2]

    # get hour minute second
    hour = split_string[1].split(':')[0]
    minute = split_string[1].split(':')[1]
    second = split_string[1].split(':')[2]

    return datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(date), hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=int(second))

filename = open('./data.txt', 'r')
frames = []
dates = []
counter = 1

for line in filename:
    # print(counter % 31)
    if line.startswith('20'):
        print(line)
        dates.append(parse_date(line))
    # frames.append(f_nov15_hereford) 

print(dates)
```

Comment: Alright, then for my program specifically I am skipping that row for now in my loop where I read in the files. So I could skip 32 rows instead of 33 but then how do I tell the function to read in the string in the first row?

Comment: If you're reading a file line by line, then you can just pass the first line to that method.

Comment: Any luck with that approach?

Comment: To be honest I am having some difficulty. This is mainly because I am reading in multiple files through a loop. So I guess I am not reading them in line by line. So I am having a hard time figuring out how to grab the first line in each file read in the loop and then set a chunksize I guess because the date time header occurs in chunks in every file read in the loop (my example data file is shown above). That is where I am stuck now. Does that make sense?

Comment: Basically, I don't want to just read in the first row, I want to read in the first row and then skip 30 lines, read that line, skip 30, read that line....etc. and then store these lines as some variable that I can read into the datetime function to convert to dates.

Comment: Are there always a consistent number of lines between the dates in the file?

Comment: Yes it is always the same

Comment: Try the code that I put in my edited answer and see if it works.

Comment: I think we are almost there. The last problem I think is that I already have a for loop in my code to read in multiple files and do this to multiple files so I am not sure if I should have a for loop inside a for loop but I tried and I got an empty array for dates.

Comment: I think that you need to move your for loop that does `for line in i` to be inside your first for loop. You also should be looping over the lines in `f_nov15_hereford` and **not** over  `line in i`.

Comment: Ok. So i just have an error when I run the code now: IndexError: list index out of range. and it points to the  month = split_string[0].split('-')[1]. I really appreciate you working through this step by step with me! I am a knew programmer.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your data and the code that you're trying to run here? http://pastie.org/. I can give you an answer if I know exactly what you're running into.

Comment: Thanks! My data is pretty long but I can copy and paste some of it. I copied and pasted it in the link but am not sure if I need to share it with you or what.

Comment: Yes. You just enter your text -- maybe just enter the first 100 lines of the file as string -- hit "create paste" and then you'll be taken to a unique link with your code. Here's what a link will look like: http://pastie.org/10709054.

Comment: Check out my edited answer. It looks like the lines all start with the same thing and don't actually occur every 33/32/31 lines.

Comment: I am so excited that we are so close! I am now getting the error:             ---> 16     hour = split_string[1].split(':')[0]
     17     min = split_string[1].split(':')[1]
     18     second = split_string[1].split(':')[2]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, and I'm also not familiar with the read_csv() method from the pandas module. Could you perhaps print out what you're passing to the `parse_date()` method that we wrote?

Comment: Ok when I print the line that I am passing to parse_date() it says:       2015-11-01 so it is not grabbing the hour, min, seconds at all I guess that is where it stops. I am not sure if that is because there is a space in my data between the date and the time?